# Application to keep track of tasks for vehicles?

Tags: asset-management

I am looking for a software to manage tasks (mostly **maintenance** and inspection) for Forklifts. Like, charge it's battery in case of an electric one or do an inspection on it. So the main points of the software:

- Should allow us to keep track of assets (a forklift, a battery in a forklift or a battery itself)
- For each asset, it should provide some kind of labelling system. Preferably a QR code with static texts, so we can print and place them on the vehicles itself.
- For each asset, allow the us to record tasks we started/completed
- Warn us If a task is due (would use it mainly to charge the batteries for every 2 months or so).
- Have mobile support

I could only find cloud based solutions which charge based on user per month and cost a lot of money. We would like a more cheaper solution. I am open to any suggestions, it could be a stand-alone software or a combination of two.